# Big-O and Big-Theta of $\sum_{i=0}^{n}{\binom{n}{i}i}$

Tags: asymptotics

I'm trying to find upper and lower limit of:

$\sum_{i=0}^{n}{\binom{n}{i}i}$

At the moment the only idea I have is:

$\sum_{i=0}^{n}{\binom{n}{i}i} \ge \sum_{i=0}^{n}{\binom{n}{i}} = 2^n$

Any other suggestion to Big-$O$ & Big-$\Theta$?

Comment: There is a closed formula for $\sum_i i\binom ni$.

Comment: Thank you @LordSharktheUnknown, Any name/reference/link ?

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n}{\binom{n}{i}i}=n2^{n-1}$$
by considering $\frac{d}{dx}(1+x)^n$ evaluated at $x=1$.

Comment: Thank you @FoobazJohn, Is it have any name?

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n}{\binom{n}{i}i} = \frac{d}{dx} \left(\sum_{i=0}^{n}{\binom{n}{i}x^i}\right)\bigg|_{x=1} = \frac{d}{dx}(x+1)^n\bigg|_{x=1}= n2^{n-1}$$

Answer (score 1):

Another derivation is based upon $\binom{n}{i}=\frac{n}{i}\binom{n-1}{i-1}$.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}i}&=n\sum_{i=1}^n\binom{n-1}{i-1}
> =n\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{i}
> \color{blue}{=n2^{n-1}}
> \end{align*}